# If a fair coin is flipped 5 times, what is the probability of getting exactly 3 heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q: "If a fair coin is flipped 5 times, what is the probability of getting exactly 3 heads?"

A: we can do this question by drawing blanks strategy.
for eg. $$\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)*10$$

but is there a way to do this same problem using combinations?
for eg. $$\dfrac{_5C_3}{_{10}C_5} = \dfrac{10}{252}$$  {so how should I get $\dfrac{10}{32}$ instead of $\dfrac{10}{252}$?}

I am really not sure how to do this using combinations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: sorry, I edited the question from my previous question modified question. This is the original question. my bad.

Comment: Where did you obtain $\binom{10}{5}$ from?  Five balls are selected.

Comment: If there were $N$ of each and you drew without replacement the answer would be $\binom N3 \times \binom N2 \big / \binom {2N}5$.  Letting $N$ grow to infinity this approximates the value you want.  It's just approximate though...for, say, $N=100$ this gives $0.315664618$ instead of $.3125$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I got 10 from the fact that we are selecting 5 balls out of a total of 10 balls. since, the balls in the bag are all equal.
actually, its a coin toss question that I have converted into a ball question. so as a coin has only 2 sides so based on that, I calculated 10 total possibilites and out of that, 5 is the number of heads (or red balls in this case.)
Edit: oops, I guess it wasn't really smart of me to convert a coin toss question into a balls question as it isn't proportional.
let me edit it into the original question. my bad. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a key element of the problem is that you have a set of possible outcomes from the sequence of coin flips, and each is equally likely.
This is true only because you have a fair coin, that is, it does not favor heads and does not favor tails.

It's because of the fact that you have a *fair coin* that you can even think about using a method where you put the number of "desired" outcomes in the numerator of a fraction and put the total number of possible outcomes in the denominator.
But since you have a fair coin, you can use that method.

Now let's count the number of outcomes to put in the denominator.

A little notation will help here. Let $H_n$ represent the fact that the coin came up heads on the $n$th flip. Let $T_n$ represent the fact that the coin came up tails on the $n$th flip.

You have noticed $10$ different things that might occur during the sequence of flips:
$$ H_1, T_1, H_2, T_2, H_3, T_3, H_4, T_4, H_5, T_5. $$
That is, there are five flips, you could get a head on any of those five flips,
and you could get a tail on any of those five flips.

It is also true that among these $10$ things that could happen, in the end there will be exactly $5$ of them that actually did happen.
You might think that this means there are $_{10}C_5$ possible outcomes for the sequence of flips--that is, choose $5$ of the $10$ things in the list.

But $_{10}C_5$ counts the number of ways to choose $5$ items from $10$ if it is possible to choose *any* five things from the list.
Given the list of $10$ things,
$ H_1, T_1, H_2, T_2, H_3, T_3, H_4, T_4, H_5, T_5, $
here is one set of $5$ things we can choose from that list:

$$ H_1, T_1, H_2, T_2, H_3. $$

What does this signify? It says the first flip came up heads but the first flip also came up tails. Likewise for the second flip. The fourth and fifth flips did not produce any results at all. Coins do not work that way.

The idea of "choose $5$ out of $10$" therefore has you counting impossible outcomes as possible outcomes. That's wrong. So $_{10}C_5$ is simply not a correct way to count the possible number of outcomes of five coin tosses.

The actual number of outcomes is $2^5 = 32.$
This is a small enough number that you can actually write every possible sequence of coin tosses on a single piece of paper in not too much time. It seems this would be a useful exercise at this point in your studies. Make sure you write each possible sequence of tosses (e.g. $H_1T_2H_3H_4H_5$) exactly once, and count them.
It helps if you write the list in a sequence with a pattern that helps you make sure you wrote every sequence and did not write any twice.

If you count the number of outcomes that way, you get the result
$$ \frac{_5C_3}{2^5} = \frac{10}{32},$$
which is the same thing you got with the "drawing blanks" method.
Note that this way of figuring the probability *does* use combinations
in the one place where it really makes sense to use combinations.

---

By the way, the answer comes out exactly the same whether you flip a fair coin $5$ times or draw $5$ times with replacement from a bag with an equal number of red and blue balls. The number of balls in the bag has no impact on the result as long as exactly half are red and half are blue.
You are equally likely to get red or blue on the first draw,
and in either of those cases, since you put the ball back in the bag before drawing again (that's what "with replacement" means), you again have equal numbers of red and blue balls before the second draw and you are equally likely to get red or blue.

Comment: Can I say that there are only 10 possibilities when drawing 5 balls from a bag of unlimited balls with an equal number of red and blue balls?
the reason I used 10C5 for a coin is because there are exactly 10 possibilities (5T+5H) when you toss a coin 5 times.
so can the same be said about balls even if the bag has unlimited number of balls?

Comment: Usually when we say there are $10$ possibilities in a probability problem, we mean $10$ possible outcomes of an entire procedure; and even before the procedure starts, we can say with certainty that at the end of the procedure, _exactly one_ of those possible outcomes will have occurred (we just don't know which one until the end) and none of the other possibilities will have occurred. There is no obvious set of $10$ possible outcomes when drawing five balls with replacement from a bag containing red and blue balls, regardless of how many balls are in the bag.

Comment: So it is actually rather nonsensical to say there are $10$ possibilities for five coin tosses. What you actually have is five separate tosses, each of which has two possibilities independent of the others. It makes sense to _multiply_ the five $2$s together (which is how we get $32$ possible outcomes for the entire sequences of flips) but not to add the $2$s together.

Answer (score 2):

Taking red balls as "success", it is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Put $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (red) and $q=1-p$ (blue), $n=5$ and $k=3$ in

$$
\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}.
$$

This reads "the probability of $k$ successes after $n$ independent trials". Since you replace the balls, each trial is an independent events.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have edited the question. sorry, I thought making equal number of red and blue balls in a bag would be equivalent to the same number of coin tosses.
it was my rookie probability mistake. I apologize. I have corrected the question. if you could, please help me with this.

Comment: true, makes perfect sense but the reason I modified the question from balls to coins is because Mr.Taussig asked me where I got the 10C5 from. so well, you see, if we are drawing 5 balls out of a bag then I can't very well say there are only 10 possibilities; whereas in 5 coin tosses, there are exactly 10 possibilities. :P
so that was my reasoning behind modifying the question. :))

Comment: or can I say that there are only 10 possibilities when drawing 5 balls from a bag of unlimited balls with an equal number of red and blue balls?
I am a rookie with probabilities, so I am not sure. :P

Comment: also, regarding your answer. yes, it's absolutely correct but I am trying to get this same answer using a Combinations method. can you help me figure out how I can get this same answer using a combinations method?
I am preparing for GMAT and bionomial distribution isn't really in the syllabus. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it using combinations.

There are $\binom53$ sequences of five coin tosses with exactly three heads. The probability of each of these is $(1/2)^5$. Therefore, the probability of three heads is $\binom53(1/2)^5.$

Your method using $\binom{10}5$ is incorrect. Nowhere are there five objects being chosen from ten.

Comment: well, i used 10C5 because there are only 10(5H and 5T) possible outcomes from tossing a coin 5 times.

Comment: @Lucky You should try to understand why ${}_{10}C_5$ does not apply here. That is for when you have $10$ **distinct** objects, your are choosing five without replacement, and order the order of the selection **does not matter.** In what you just described, the objects $\{H,H,H,H,H,T,T,T,T,T\}$ are **not distinct** (the H and T are repeated), and here the order **does matter**, as TTHHH is different than HHHTT.

Comment: but isn't it like a bag having 10 balls with 5 Red and 5 Blue balls?

Comment: @Lucky No. The coin flips are independent; the draws from a bag of 10 ball are not. When your first ball is red, the probability the next balls is red is 4/9. But for independent coin flips, the probability is supposed to be 1/2 each time.

Comment: with replacement I mean

Comment: @Lucky With replacement, the number of ways to choose $5$ balls from the bag is not ${}_{10}C_5$ anymore. You only use ${}_nC_k$ for choosing without replacement. If you choose without replacement, the number of ways is $2^5$.

Comment: interesting. so we can't use Combinations in situations where there is replacement?

Answer (score 1):

The logic you have applied to answer this question is faulty. There are totally 5 trials, and each trial will give either Head or Tail. And what you have done is that you have made a sample space by combining all the elements, you have put all the possible 5 heads and 5 tails. You can't simply create a sample space by putting all the elements of 5 trials together. 
Rather, the actual sample  space should be like {HHHHH, TTTTT, HHHHT,.... ,}, 
 not, {H, H, H, H, H, T, T, T, T, T} which you have done. 
Now, it can be solved by combination.

Comment: well, if lets say that a bag contained 10 balls with 5 Blue and 5 Red balls and the withdrawl was with replacement then wouldn't it be the same situation as flipping a coin 5 times?

Comment: No, certainly not. Both ball and coin situation you have in your mind are not same. Just imagine, if you have 5 red and 5 blue balls as you have said.. You have all ten balls before your eyes, you can pick any one of the ten. But, in the coin situation, you have a single coin, with just have 1 head and 1 tail. To get more than 1 head, you need to repeat the experiment again. Physically you just have 1 coin(1 head and 1 tail), whereas in ball situation, you had all the 10 balls.